# CSS:hover not working when using animation key frames

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm using animation for web page and  I'm trying to apply a simple hover effect to list on the page. But it's not working, the following is my code.

I suspect animation is not allowing CSS. While checking with inspecting elements with hover, it's working

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

body{
    font-family: Baloo;
    display: flex;
}

.banner-text{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.banner-text ul{
    height: 50px;
    float: right;

}

.banner-text ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 40px 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.banner-text ul li:hover{
     color: red;
}


.banner-text h2{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 20%;
}


.animation-area{
    background: linear-gradient(to left,#8942a8,#ba382f);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.box-area{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box-area li{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    animation: animate 20s alternate infinite;
    bottom: -120px;

}

.box-area li:nth-child(1){
    left: 86%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 90px;
    animation-delay: 0;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(2){
    left: 12%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    
}

.box-area li:nth-child(3){
    left: 70%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 5.5s;
}


.box-area li:nth-child(4){
    left: 70%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: 15s;
}

.box-area li:nth-child(5){
    left: 65%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
.box-area li:nth-child(6){
    left: 15%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-text">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>about</a></li>
        <li><a>careers</a></li>
        <li><a>contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
</div>
<div class="animation-area">
    <ul class="box-area">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please suggest the code to work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with your CSS animation, this is a simple `z-index` problem, your `.animation-area` lays over the `.banner-text` area.

Just give your `.banner-text` area a `z-indez: 1;` and everything will work fine.

Remember that z-index only works positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and it's the property that specifies the stack order of an element.

Here's a working live [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alezucc/mL02oa7b/3/)

```css
   *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            
        }
        
        body{
            font-family: Baloo;
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .banner-text{
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .banner-text ul{
            height: 50px;
            float: right;
        
        }
        
        .banner-text ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 40px 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        
        .banner-text ul li:hover{
             color: red;
        }
        
        
        .banner-text h2{
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 50px;
            margin-top: 20%;
        }
        
        
        .animation-area{
            background: linear-gradient(to left,#8942a8,#ba382f);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        
        .box-area{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        .box-area li{
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            list-style: none;
            width: 25px;
            height: 25px;
            border-radius: 90px;
            background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
            animation: animate 20s alternate infinite;
            bottom: -120px;
        
        }
        
        .box-area li:nth-child(1){
            left: 86%;
            width: 80px;
            height: 90px;
            animation-delay: 0;
        }
        
        .box-area li:nth-child(2){
            left: 12%;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            animation-delay: 1.5s;
            animation-duration: 10s;
            
        }
        
        .box-area li:nth-child(3){
            left: 70%;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            animation-delay: 5.5s;
        }
        
        
        .box-area li:nth-child(4){
            left: 70%;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            animation-delay: 0s;
            animation-duration: 15s;
        }
        
        .box-area li:nth-child(5){
            left: 65%;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            animation-delay: 0s;
        }
        .box-area li:nth-child(6){
            left: 15%;
            width: 110px;
            height: 110px;
            animation-delay: 3.5s;
        }
        
        @keyframes animate{
            0%{
                transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
                opacity: 1;
            }
            100%{
                transform: translateY(-800px) rotate(360deg);
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }
```

```html
   <div class="banner-text">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>about</a></li>
                    <li><a>careers</a></li>
                    <li><a>contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h2>Welcome to my website</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="animation-area">
                <ul class="box-area">
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

For more information about z-index, please read [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm new to ui and this solution is working.